# How to display data of specific current logged in user in Firebase Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need help in my code. Please tell me how to display the data entered by specific current logged in user only. Like, filtering data that if one user uploads a data, he/she could only see her/his data, but not others (Firebase Database). Here's my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.timothy.chlogbook1.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Database extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editTextDate;
    EditText editTextName;
    EditText editTextMethod;
    EditText editTextTopics;
    EditText editTextSummary;
    Button buttonAdd;
    Spinner spinnerGrade;

    DatabaseReference databaseLogbook;
    ListView listViewLogbook;
    List<Logbook> logbookList;
    FirebaseUser user;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_database);

        databaseLogbook = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Logbook");


        editTextDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDate);
        buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextMethod = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMethod);
        editTextTopics = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTopics);
        editTextSummary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSummary);
        spinnerGrade = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerGrade);

        listViewLogbook = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewLogbook);
        logbookList = new ArrayList<>();

        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addLogbook();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseLogbook.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                logbookList.clear();

                for(DataSnapshot logbookSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Logbook logbook = logbookSnapshot.getValue(Logbook.class);

                    logbookList.add(logbook);

                }

                LogbookList adapter = new LogbookList(Database.this, logbookList);
                listViewLogbook.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void addLogbook(){
        String date = editTextDate.getText().toString().trim();
        String fullname = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        String grade = spinnerGrade.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String method = editTextMethod.getText().toString().trim();
        String topics = editTextTopics.getText().toString().trim();
        String summary = editTextSummary.getText().toString().trim();


        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(fullname)) {

            String id = databaseLogbook.push().getKey();
            Logbook logbook = new Logbook(id,date,fullname,grade,method,topics,summary);
            databaseLogbook.child(id).setValue(logbook);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Logbook Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "You should enter your full name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

So in this code, It can show the data in Firebase database, but, It shows all data.

Answer (score 0):

For writing data to firebase:

```
    private void addLogbook(){
        String date = editTextDate.getText().toString().trim();
        String fullname = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        String grade = spinnerGrade.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String method = editTextMethod.getText().toString().trim();
        String topics = editTextTopics.getText().toString().trim();
        String summary = editTextSummary.getText().toString().trim();


        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(fullname)) {

//            String id = databaseLogbook.push().getKey();
            Logbook logbook = new Logbook(date,fullname,grade,method,topics,summary);
            String userEmail = UserEmailIdString.replace(".", ",");
            databaseLogbook.child(userEmail).setValue(logbook);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Logbook Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "You should enter your full name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

For reading data from firebase:

```
String userEmail = UserEmailIdString.replace(".", ",");
databaseLogbook = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Logbook")
.child(userEmail);
```

By this way of reading and writing, only logged in user will see their data

Comment: Hi Rahul Chandrabhan, Really, Thank you!!, but I'm getting an error at this line Logbook logbook = new Logbook(id,date,fullname,grade,method,topics,summary); (in the id).

Comment: And btw, when I erased the id variable my app crashed.

Comment: oh, I got a Java Null Pointer Exception at this line too. String userEmail = user.getEmail().replace(".", ",");
        databaseLogbook = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Logbook")
                .child(userEmail); The "replace" produced a java null pointer exception

Comment: Do you have the user email id?

Comment: And sorry I could only comment because I have to wait 4 days to post another question.

Comment: Do you have the logged in user email id?

Comment: Yes Rahul ChandraBhan

Comment: See my edited answer, replace your addlogbook() method, and UserEmailIdString is your logged in user email id, change it too

Comment: sorry, I should replace my addlogbook() method with what? and maybe we could do contact in email? here's my email: timothi.dillan10@gmail.com

Comment: sorry sir, i'm really a beginner into firebase and android, so please don't be mad if i dont understand

Comment: maybe you could give me your mail?

Comment: and i'm getting an error cannot resolve symbol "UserEmailIdString"

Comment: Just select all your addLogBook() method and paste my addlogBook() method over it. it is simple. And userEmailIdString is the user email id you have. I am using this email id as an unique path

Comment: sorry but i still got an error cannot resolve symbol "UserEmailIdString"

Comment: can you give me your email so we can talk there?

Comment: UserEmailIdString is the email id of the user which is logged in. You told me you have that thing. User it there.

Comment: I dont understand, could you give me an example?

Comment: Timothy are you using FIrebase Authentication for login purpose?

Comment: Then use firebase user to get Email id of the user. I hope you know that